# Install Ubuntu in USB drive

Tags: installation, 13.04, usb

how to install ubuntu in pen drive and use it in any computer.
LiveUSB doesnt save my changes and delete files, i dont want that.
I want to install as if it was installed in my internal drive

Answer (score 0):

The following link is a pretty good tutorial.

http://www.howtogeek.com/97177/how-to-put-ubuntu-linux-on-a-usb-thumb-drive-without-the-mess/